# consumer method inside subscribe() is only called once

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

so i have this method below which starts a timer when i click a button 'B' 
after 59 seconds the timerview's invisibility is set as gone, the code is working fine except,
when i click on button 'B' again to start the whole process once more,
nothing happens!
why is that?

```
@Override
public void timerStart() {

  getCompositeDisposable()
      .add(Observable.interval(0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                         @Override
                         public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                             if (time > 0) {
                                 String timer = String.format("%s:%s", "00", time <= 9 ? "0" + time : String.valueOf(time));
                                 getMvpView().updateTimer(timer);
                                 time--;
                             } else {
                                 getMvpView().hideTimer();
                             }
                         }
                     }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                 getMvpView().hideTimer();
                             }
                         }
              )
      );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of variable **time**. Maybe it can't be positive again after the first call of timestart(). (your portion of code does not show which other function can update time or where is the initialisation)

Comment: maybe that's the issue, i'll check if that's the case